# Error when deploying token with tax feature on bsc mainnet

Tags: solidity, binance

when I am trying to deploy the contract on bsc mainnet I receive this message

Gas estimation errored with the following message (see below). The transaction execution will likely fail. Do you want to force sending?
Returned error: {"jsonrpc":"2.0","error":"execution reverted","id":3754132915077466}

I mention that I do not have any experience in programming.
thank you for helping !

Comment: Please edit the question and paste the contract code as text (not as image). You can use markdown or the `{}` symbol in editor... The reason why deployment fails is often because an uncaught exception is thrown in the constructor.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.